# How to select string data and exclude data contain zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `ElectronicAddress` like below, and a string type column `Phone`.

```
Id      Name      Phone
 --------------------------
1     Adele     23432434
2     Diana     0000
3     Whale     0000000
4     Sion      936
5     Aria      wwqq
6     Dave      665332
7     Daisy     dai567
```

i want to select `Phone` which is exclude zero only, exclude character only and must have > 5 characters.

Result i'm trying to get :

```
Id      Name      Phone
 --------------------------
1     Adele     23432434
6     Dave      665332
7     Daisy     dai567
```

i already try this :

`select * from ElectronicAddress where Phone not like '[[:alpha:] -]' and LENGTH(TRIM(Phone)) >5`

but i'm having a hard time to exclude data contain zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply 3 conditions in the WHERE clause:

```
select * from ElectronicAddress
where 
  regexp_like("Phone", '[[:digit:]]') 
  and length("Phone") > 5 
  and replace("Phone", '0', '') is not null
```

Oracle treats empty strings as `null`s, this is why you need `is not null`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f19016c64d5829bf399b2595b5ff5398).
Results:

```
> Id | Name  | Phone   
> -: | :---- | :-------
>  1 | Adele | 23432434
>  6 | Dave  | 665332  
>  7 | Daisy | Dai567
```

Answer (score 0):

By "exclude 0" you seem to mean "exclude strings that only consist of zeros" rather than exclude `'0'` (as I originally interpreted it).  That piece is harder to incorporate into a single regular expression, so separate logic can be used.

I think you want only digits:

```
where regexp_like(phone, '^[0-9]{5,}$') and replace(phone, '0', '') is not null
```

Or:

```
where regexp_like(phone, '^[^a-zA-Z]{5,}$') and replace(phone, '0', '') is not null
```

Or:

```
where regexp_like(phone, '^[^[:alpha]]{5,}$') and replace(phone, '0', '') is not null
```

You can also do this in one regular expression.  I'm not sure if there is a cleaner method.  The following is brute force, looking for a non-zero digit in any of the first five positions:

```
where regexp_like(phone, '^[1-9][0-9]{4,}$|^[0-9]{1}[1-9][0-9]{3,}$|^[0-9]{2}[1-9][0-9]{2,}$|^[0-9]{3}[1-9][0-9]{1,}$|^[0-9]{4}[1-9][0-9]*$')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab6ea645248fb8a90bc21ced38091035) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You still need remove the all 0's row?

Comment: yes. i only need data with > 5 characters and alphanumeric.

Comment: @EdmundXavier . . . What do you mean by "exclude 0"?

Comment: exclude data contain zero value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Yourtable
WHERE length (phone) > 5 
  and REPLACE(Phone, '0', '') <> ''
  and LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(Phone, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) = 0
```